# How can i design a "family tree" -like UI?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

[image]

I want to create a dynamic interactive tree structure like shown in image?

All i found is it can be done using **fragments** can someone show me how to implement just top two nodes with their links using fragments?

Comment: You can do that with a RelativeLayout but it isn't going to be easy.

Comment: You will probably need to create your custom view, this would be brutal with standard views.. What have you tried so far?

Comment: canvas, grid of coordinates, paints and bitmaps

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763352/how-do-i-show-marriages-in-a-d3-js-based-family-tree) help?

Answer (score -1):

Have a horizontal linearlayout for each row and put each row in a vertical linearlayout. Create one view as a base for each image and text that is included and just use ´include´ to use that base view for each image\text. If you use an id for each included view you can grab each id and configure them separately in Java if needed.