# How to create family tree with d3 js

Tags: d3.js

Can anyone point me to the right direction, i'm building a  family tree chart with custom layout using d3.js, As i know it is possible to show parents and childrens using hierarchal tree layout, but i don't get on how to display partners and sibling. Any ideas on how to do it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I found your question very general.  Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763352/how-do-i-show-marriages-in-a-d3-js-based-family-tree

Comment: This one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245751/how-do-you-create-a-family-tree-in-d3-js/31367673#31367673

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A project I'm working on requires building a pedigree tree, and I've found using [Dagre-d3](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3) works quite well. Have a look at the [Sentence Tokenization](http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/sentence-tokenization.html) demo to get started in the right direction.